does glibc support c++?
According to wiki page of glibc, glibc directly supports C++ nowadays.  To the best of my knowledge, glibc is just a C library, and has no C++ standard library. Somebody may argue that there is some latent support for C++. But this reference explicitly denote that glibc directly supports C++. How can that be possible??
wiki page of glibc：https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc

The GNU C Library, commonly known as glibc, is the GNU Project implementation of the C standard library. It is a wrapper around the system calls of the Linux kernel for application use. Despite its name, it now also directly supports C++ (and, indirectly, other programming languages).

I search for header file in source code of glibc-2.18, and it seems that there is no C++ headers.

Maybe this first time mentioned C++ support in GLIBC 2.18: Add support for calling C++11 thread_local object destructors on thread and program exit.  This needs compiler support for offloading C++11 destructor calls to glibc, New ISO C++1x interfaces: quick_exit, at_quick_exit Implemented by Ulrich Drepper, Correct declarations of string function when used in C++ code.  This could lead to compile errors for invalid C++ code. Unnecessity of -lpthread is also might be considered as a direct C++ support.

Wikipedia early on 2015-03-22 did not mention "Despite its name, …".  Later on the same day, the comment was added.  So, the comment has been around for a long time.  There is no link/citation to justify the assertion.  It isn't clear what the comment means, even — at least, I don't find it clear.  I observe that Wikipedia is not as authoritative as GNU's website is likely to be, but it does have background information that isn't widely available elsewhere.

@JonathanLeffler The comment of the edit: C++ support (exceptions at least).

@3CxEZiVlQ — And what does that mean?

"Directly supports" probably means all the care that's been put into the C library to make it usable from C++ and other languages. From the README:

The GNU C Library is the standard system C library for all GNU systems, and is an important part of what makes up a GNU system.  It provides the system API for all programs written in C and C-compatible languages such as C++ and Objective C; the runtime facilities of other programming languages use the C library to access the underlying operating system.

It does however not contain C++ headers. It does however contain some ~900 lines mentioning __cplusplus to make it useable from C++. It also has a few (36) extern "C++" declared functions, mainly in math.h, stdlib.h, string.h and wchar.h.
A commit from 2013 mentions:

In the string/string.h and string/strings.h headers, we have a couple of macros that "tell the caller that we provide correct C++ prototypes" according to the comment; they are used to determine whether to wrap some prototypes in "extern "C++"" (and provide multiple overloads of them, and some other magic) when __cplusplus is defined.

So, it is a C library, where adaptions for other languages to be able to use it has been made where needed.

Other things that a C library has to do in order to support usage from C++ include: avoid use of identifiers that are C++ keywords but not C keywords in all header files; ensure that all struct types have the same layout in C++ as in C (this is why glibc's headers use so many explicit padding fields); ensure that all struct types have stable mangled names; support "unwinding" through the C library if e.g. a qsort comparison function throws a C++ exception; and that's just what comes immediately to mind.

@zwol Yes, very true. I noticed that the __cplusplus macro is used in many places to avoid a lot of the identifier problems.

It gets especially fun when there's some third specification (not necessarily a formal standard, "backward compatibility with 4.4BSD" counts) that requires some public interface to have a name that collides with a C++ keyword or a commonly used C++ standard library interface.  (This is why glibc's sys/types.h had to stop defining the macros for operating on dev_t values, iirc.)

The "it now also directly supports C++" words were added to the glibc Wikipedia page in this version, on 22 March 2015.  The differences can be seen at https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Glibc&diff=prev&oldid=653048486
The glibc version history on that pages mentions this for glibc 2.18:

2.18     August 2013        Improved C++11 support...


Per the glibc 2.18 change log, we find this:

Add support for calling C++11 thread_local object destructors on thread
and program exit.  This needs compiler support for offloading C++11
destructor calls to glibc.

A quick reading of the glibc change logs from 2.19 to 2.35 available at https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=timeline&l=glibc does not seem to document any other C++ support being added to glibc.
So, if you account for cleaning up C++11 thread_local objects, glibc does "support" C++.

No, there's no header files for C++ like e.g. <iostream> because libc is not a C++ library, it only supports it.  The library you search for is libstdc++, and it is a C++ library that installs on top of libc (this is, is supported by, or requires).  It is completely supported by glibc (because it requires it)  but as the documentation you cite says, libc is a C library, not a C/C++ libray.  Don't confound supports with implements.
Have you installed g++?  if you do, you will get that library for development purposes.
